# Mathieu group $M_{23}$ as an algebraic group via additive polynomials

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, polynomials, finite-groups

An elegant description of the Mathieu group $M_{23}$ is the following: Let $C$ be the multiplicative subgroup of order $23$ in the field $F=\mathbb F_{2^{11}}$ with $2^{11}$ elements. Then $M_{23}$ is the group of additive maps of $F$ to itself which permute the set $C$. The restriction to $C$ then is the natural action of $M_{23}$ of degree $23$.

Any additive map of $F$ to itself has the form $x\mapsto\sum_{i=0}^{10}a_ix^{2^i}$ for $a_i\in F$. The condition that such maps preserve $C$ can be expressed easily as an equivalent set of polynomial conditions on the coefficients $a_0,\dots,a_{10}$. For instance, for a variable $t$, compare coefficients of $$\prod_{c\in C}(t-\sum_{i=0}^{10}a_ic^{2^i})=t^{23}-1.$$ In addition, we need the equations $a_i^{2^{11}}=a_i$ to ensure that the $a_i$ are in $F$.

However, the polynomials we obtain this way (or some other way, there are somewhat smarter possibilities) are extremely complicated.

Of course, any finite subgroup of a linear group is an algebraic set, that is a solution of a system of polynomial equations. And in general such a system will be messy.

Here, I somehow expect that there should be a simple system of polynomials discribing $M_{23}$ as an algebraic set. The obvious attempt would be to first take a system as above, and then hope that a Groebner basis looks better. After some naive attempts it seems that the systems are too complex for Magma or Singular to compute the Groebner bases.

Before trying to refine the approach, here is my question: Has anyone seen this version to describe $M_{23}$?

Comment: This looks like a reasonable (though maybe quite difficult) question.    But I wonder what consequences such a description would have?

Comment: the natural object preserved by the group here is dual of the perfect binary Golay code https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_Golay_code
One might ask for similar descriptions of smaller codes to begin with.

Comment: E.g. one may ask for such a description for PSL(3,2): I suppose you have to replace 11 by 3 and 23 by 7, i.e. $|C|=7$ and $F=\mathbb{F}_{2^3}$, and consider PSL(3,2) as the group of additive maps of $F$ preserving $C$. (Disclaimer---I didn't check all the details here :-)).

Comment: @JimHumphreys I hope to use it for certain combinatorial questions about $M_{23}$, for instance in the study of sharply transitive sets of permutations. Such question have a polynomial formulation, so if the $M_{23}$ has a nice polynomial formulation too, I have some hope.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Right, one could try some smaller toy examples. The group $PSL(3,2)$ maybe is not that interesting though, because it equals $GL(3,2)$. So all that we polynomially encode would be bijectivity of the linear maps.

Comment: It is known how to express generators of $M_{23}$ as a permutation group in terms of rational univariate maps over $\mathbb{F}_{23}$. (Not sure about the original reference, I saw it in a book by D. Gorenstein http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=698782). More precisely, it gives such representation for $M_{24}$, as the maps in PSL(2,23) and one extra binomial of relatively high degree.

Comment: @DimaPasechnik Yes, I know that. But I believe that has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: one natural way to produce an explicit set of equations is to identify a polynomial $p$ left invariant by $M_{23}$, but not by any overgroup of it in GL(11,2), and write down equations for the matrix entries saying that  $p$ is invariant.

Comment: Why are you not happy with just defining the $G$ as the subgroup $\mathrm{GL}_{11}$ that preserves $C$? then $G(\mathbf{F}_2)$ is reduced to the Mathieu group. No need to incorporate the conditions that entries are in $\mathbf{F}_2$: this is part of the definition of $G(\mathbf{F}_2)$. If $G$ is defined as I just did, I don't even know if it's positive-dimensional.

Comment: @YCor: I tried to answer that in my first comment above.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you don't know the answer (whether $G$ has positive dimension, where $G\subset\mathrm{GL}_{11}$ is the stabilizer of $C$).

Comment: The additive subgroup generated by $C$ is a subfield, is not reduced to $F_2$, and hence equals $F_{11}$. Hence the fixator of $C$ in $GL_{11}$ is reduced to the trivial subgroup. Hence the stabilizer $G$ of $C$ in $GL_{11}$ is finite (as an algebraic group). Since $|C|=23$ and the dimension is 11, there exists a 3-element subset $F$ of $C$ such that $C-F$ generates $F_{11}$ additively. Hence a 3-cycle on $F$ cannot belong to $G(K)$ for any extension $K$ of $F_2$. So the (faithful) action of $G(K)$ on $C$ is reduced to $M_{23}$, and hence $G(K)$ is reduced to $G(F_2)=M_{23}$ for every $K$.

Comment: This is a very old question, but I can't help adding the following comment, that may or may not be relevant. I wonder whether Abhyankar's paper, "Mathieu group coverings in characteristic two" is relevant here? He demonstrates that there are very innocuous looking degree 23 trinomials over ${\mathbb F}_2(X)$ with Galois group $M_{23}$. His example is $Y^{23}+XY^3+1$.

Comment: @DaveBenson Indeed, I had also tried something along this idea. The upper bound of the Galois group of $Y^{23}+XY^3+1$ is achieved by showing that this polynomial divides an additive polynomial of degree $2^{11}$. So actually this additive polynomial has Galois group $M_{23}$, and its groups acts on an $11$-dimensional $\mathbb F_2$-space.